# Node JS live text update with CloudMQTT

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node server which is connecting to CloudMQTT and receiving messages in app.js.  I have my client web app running on the same node server and want to display my messages received in app.js elsewhere in a .ejs file, I'm struggling as to how best to do this.

```
app.js
// Create a MQTT Client
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

// Create a client connection to CloudMQTT for live data
var client = mqtt.connect('xxxxxxxxxxx', {
  username: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxxxx' 
});

client.on('connect', function() { // When connected
    console.log("Connected to CloudMQTT");
  // Subscribe to the temperature
  client.subscribe('Motion', function() {
    // When a message arrives, do something with it
    client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
      // ** Need to pass message out **
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You could use socket.io to realtime update client in browser.

Comment: Could you please share your code for connecting cloud mqtt and Nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need a way for the client (browser code with EJS - HTML, CSS and JS) to receive live updates. There are basically two ways to do this from the client to the node service:

1. A [websocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) session instantiated by the client.
2. A [polling](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling) approach.

What's the difference?

Under the hood, a websocket is full-duplex communication mechanism. That means that you can open a socket from the client (browser) to the node server and they can talk to each other both ways over a long-lived session. The pro is that updates are often times instantaneous without having to incur the cost of making another HTTP request as in the polling case. The con is that it uses a socket connection that may be long-lived, and there is typically a socket pool on any server that has limited ability to deal with many sockets. There are ways to scale around this issue, but if it's a big concern for you, you may want to go with polling.

Polling is where you set up an endpoint on your server that the client JS code hits every now and then. That endpoint will return you the updated information. The con is that you are now making a new request in order to get updates, which may not be desirable if a lot of updates are expected to come through and the app is expected to be updated in the timeliest manner possible (most of the time polling is sufficient though). The pro is that you do not have a live connection open on the server indefinitely.

Again, there are many more pros and cons, these are just the obvious ones. You decide how to implement it. When the client receives the data from either of these mechanisms, you may update the UI in any suitable manner.

From the server end, you will need a way to persist the information coming from CloudMQTT. There are multiple ways to do this. If you do not care about memory consumption and are ok with potentially throwing away old data if a client does not ask for it for a while, then it may be ok to just store this in memory in a regular javascript object `{}`. If you do care about persisting the data between server restarts/crashes (probably best), then you can persist to something like [Redis](http://redis.io/), [Mongo](https://www.mongodb.org/), any of the SQL stores if your data is relational in nature, or even a regular JSON file on disk (see [fs.writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback)).

Hope this helped give you a step in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did look at socket io initially.  I will try to implement this.

Comment: @Carl :Could you please share your code for connecting mqtt and Nodejs?